# Select MAX or SUM

Tags: sql

[image]

Simply, I have exam note for many Student for many exam,
see the picture below **(MATH = 0, BIOLOGY = 2, ALGEBRA = 1)**
I just want to give the student the Max notes = The Student have 2 = on BIOLOGY so ALGEBRA AND MATH must be at 2

**Try to have this :**

[image]

I try this :

```
SELECT First_Name, EXAM, MAX(NOTE)
FROM My_Table
Group by First_Name, EXAM
```

Not working, still give me this **(MATH = 0, BIOLOGY = 2, ALGEBRA = 1)**

Try also :

```
SELECT First_Name, EXAM, 
CASE
  WHEN SUM(NOTE) <> 0 THEN MAX(NOTE)
Else 0
END AS MAX_NOTE
FROM My_Table
```

Not working

Please do you have any idea ? or solution ? Click to check see the picture (screenshot)

Comment: Use a windowed aggregate. Also, I've removed the conflicting dialect tags; T-SQL is used by SQL Server and PL/SQL by Oracle. Tag correctly, please.

Comment: The editing was harder than the answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `group by`, and use a window function to take care of per-student logic:

```
SELECT First_Name, EXAM, MAX(NOTE) over (partition by First_Name)
FROM My_Table
```

Comment: ===>>  Thank you very much .. It's work very well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    First_Name, 
    EXAM, 
    MAX(NOTE) OVER(partition by First_Name) as MAX_NOTE
FROM 
    My_Table
```

Reference for using Max and OVER together in SQL Server:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: ====>> Thank you very much

Sincerely It Help me a lot

Comment: Please upvote and accept it as an answer, if the solution has worked for you.